# I want to use clickable text (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use clickable text to move from main activity to another activity, can somebody give me a sample code to understand that how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the layout of your activity, define the onclick on the textview item.

```
<TextView ....
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true" ... </TextView>
```

OnClick Method

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know the reason why people have down voted my question but they should understand that i am really starting out with android and its been only 3 days since i started learning android.